# git pull command using Ansible

Tags: git, ansible

Can anyone please advice me what is the difference between the following ansible git module and git command

while i'm using the git module in playbook its overwriting a file which it shouldn't, while the git command does not overwrite the file

I have tried to translate the GIT command into a task in the playbook

### ANSIBLE GIT MODULE

```
- name: pull v016 repo from git
    git: repo=https://{{ githubuser }}:{{ githubpassword|urlencode }}@git.abc.com/abc/abc.git
         dest=/tmp/test/abc
         accept_hostkey=yes
         update=yes
         clone=no
         force=yes
         remote=origin
         version=20190524v016
```

### GIT COMMAND

```
git pull origin 20190524v016 --tags
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in [`ansible/modules/source_control/git.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c5a2ba5217dbb75998f61d86b83700b912f29054/lib/ansible/modules/source_control/git.py#L1192-L1199) is clear:

```rb
    else:
        # else do a pull
        local_mods = has_local_mods(module, git_path, dest, bare)
        result['before'] = get_version(module, git_path, dest)
        if local_mods:
            # failure should happen regardless of check mode
            if not force:
                module.fail_json(msg="Local modifications exist in repository (force=no).", **result)
```

So getting this error message on the "before" `git pull` part is expected.

The [`has_local_mods()`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c5a2ba5217dbb75998f61d86b83700b912f29054/lib/ansible/modules/source_control/git.py#L515-L524) function is:

```rb
def has_local_mods(module, git_path, dest, bare):
    if bare:
        return False

    cmd = "%s status --porcelain" % (git_path)
    rc, stdout, stderr = module.run_command(cmd, cwd=dest)
    lines = stdout.splitlines()
    lines = list(filter(lambda c: not re.search('^\\?\\?.*$', c), lines))

    return len(lines) > 0
```

> While I'm using the git module in playbook its overwriting a file which it shouldn't, while the git command does not overwrite the file

That is the puzzling part: double-check the `git status --porcelain` output (when done in command-line), to see if your file is actually modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html#git-module

```
force=yes
```

> If yes, any modified files in the working repository will be discarded. Prior to 0.7, this was always 'yes' and could not be disabled. Prior to 1.9, the default was `yes`

I.e., set `force=no` to not overwrite the file.

Comment: playbook is failing with the below error if force=no is set

    fatal: []: FAILED! => {"before": "23300bf0eab215bc21cba285c2a43c39ba004b24", "changed": false, "msg": "Local modifications exist in repository (force=no)."}

Comment: Seems module `git` doesn't allow to pull into a repo with modifications. My advice is to use `command` or `shell` modules. Or stash/unstash the modifications before/after pulling.